# Class Iron MQ Not Found - Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, iron

I'm trying to follow the reliable Jeffrey Wrays' Laracast - https://laracasts.com/lessons/ironclad-queues

But am having an issue when trying to run a que command. I keep getting the error :

> {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class
>   'IronMQ' not
>   found","file":"C:\xampp\htdocs\theedstore-co-uk\_____vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\IronConnector.php","line":49}}

I've followed what the Iron_MQ Git hub says :

> If you're using laravel and see "Class IronMQ not found" error set
>   iron_mq version to 1.* and install dependencies

My compser.json file looks as so :

```
  "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "way/generators": "~2.0",
    "zizaco/confide": "~4.3@dev",
    "way/database": "dev-master",
    "hugofirth/mailchimp": "2.0.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4.*",
    "torann/currency": "dev-master",
    "thomaswelton/laravel-gravatar": "0.1.x",
    "intervention/image": "dev-master",
    "laracasts/flash": "1.0",
    "moltin/currency": "1.0.*@dev",
    "moltin/tax": "dev-master",
    "moltin/cart": "dev-master",
    "moltin/laravel-cart": "dev-master",
    "nqxcode/zendsearch": "dev-master",
    "nqxcode/laravel-lucene-search": "dev-master",
    "philipbrown/worldpay": "~3.0",
    "guzzle/guzzle": "3.8.*@dev",
    "vinkla/vimeo": "~1.0",
    "iron-io/iron_core": "1.*",
    "iron-io/iron_mq": "1.*"
```

I've even tried removing the Vendor folder and the .lock file, But still get the error.

Does anyone have anymore suggestions. I just cannot get Iron.io to work in my project.

Cheers

Comment: `iron_mq` is up to version 3, use that instead? `"iron-io/iron_mq": "~3.0"` – See https://packagist.org/packages/iron-io/iron_mq

Comment: And remove `"iron-io/iron_core": "1.*",`, it's already included in `iron_mq`.

Comment: Cheers @Marwelln removing iron-io/iron_core and reverting to ~3.0 has worked a treat.

Comment: @Marwelln You should put your comments into an Answer so it can be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but it was solved when i used this version

```
"iron-io/iron_mq": "~3.0"
```

You have to delete composer.lock and run:

```
composer update
```